# How do I split one string into two strings in Kotlin with "."?

Tags: string, kotlin, split

Let's say I have this string:

```
val mainString: String = "AAA.BBB"
```

And now I define two children strings:

```
val firstString: String = ""
val secondString: String = ""
```

What code should I write to make firstString equals to "AAA", and secondString equals to "BBB"?

Answer (score 2):

The below code works for any amount of strings separated by delimiters

```
val texto = "111.222.333"  
val vet = texto.split(".")
for (st in vet)  println(st)
```

It prints

```
111
222
333
```

Comment: Thanks! but is there a way to put the two strings in two different variables instead of printing them? In my app, there are only two strings separated with a "."

Comment: @GiladSusel yes, `val (part1, part2, /* ... */) = text..split(".")`, see [Destructing Declarations](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/multi-declarations.html)